# Bash Permission Denied on all files in my ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, permissions

I just logged into my linux ssh that I had been using all last year for the first time since Holiday break and I am trying to view my files with `less file` and `head file` but I am getting `Permission Denied`. When I try to use these files in codes I am getting errors because they can't be opened. I tried looking at `ls -l` to check permissions and all of the files have `-rw-------.` permissions. Should I be able to read them then? How can I change them all back to normal so I can use them?

Comment: It's a linux server. It's a ssh at a university that I have been using to do research. I just logged in after the holidays and I am presented with this issue. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What could have possibility happened to cause this?

Comment: @Evan try this on one file `chmod 644 file` and then see if you can access it

Comment: `"changing permission of file: Permission Denied"`

Answer (score 3):

in the first column as you have implies that only the owner [and root] can read and write the files.

When you do an ls -l  the second and third column show the name of the owner - if thats not you, you need to speak to the system administrator to make it you !

If it IS you, then there is most likely a problem with SELinux or Apparmor, but this is a lot less likely.